# Android app code coverage for manual testing

Tags: android, code-coverage, emma, manual-testing

I am looking for a way to get EMMA code coverage with manual test. I mean, i don't want to write any unit test cases using the android test framework, instead i am looking for a way to instrument my android app source code and test manually and at the end i should be able to see my EMMA coverage. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you figure out how to run a test suite at all I'd like to know. Every time I try to execute a test in eclipse it throws up a Java crash.

Answer (score 2):

Nearly a month and you have no responses.

You might consider using a test coverage tool that isn't tied to the infrastructure in the way Emma is.  This avoids the problems with incompatabilities with said infrastructure.

Our [Java Test Coverage](http://wwww.semanticdesigns.com/Products/TestCoverage/JavaTestCoverage.html) tool instruments your *source* code, making it independent of the compiler and runtime system.  You compile your code and execute/test it however your like (system tests, unit tests, manual interaction), and it collects test coverage data in a Java array in a TestCoverage class, as the tests run.   At the end of execution (you define that, although exit from main is a common definition), that test coverage data is written *somehow* to a file, eventually to be displayed by the test coverage tool.   While the Java Test Coverage tool provides a default class implementation that writes the array to a disk file using Java file primitives, you can easily override the implementation with any code you like, and store the array in any place where it can be eventually retrieved by another mechanism to be turned into a file, and then displayed.

This will work with your manual exercising of code.

Answer (score 0):

Try using below post. This seems to have worked for lot of people.

http://dtmilano.blogspot.com/2011/11/obtaining-code-coverage-of-running.html